# Canon ImageRunner Advance C5550 driver for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, network-printer

Windows 10 does manage to install the printer and I can print to it successfully. However, I do not get all of the options. I see this is Word:
[Basic printer dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgnXb.png)

For instance, I know there is functionality with this printer for "print and hold" which will allow me to send the document to the printer, but then go to the printer itself and log in, in order to print the document while I am there.

I need this functionality for when printing confidential documents.

The full UI should look like this according to the manual: [Custom printer dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KGIf.png), available at http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300025656/03/iRADV_C5560_FAQ_EU_multi_2.pdf

The drivers page contains 52 available downloads for my OS/language combination and I have no idea what to install! https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-advance-c5550i.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=windows%2010%20(64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

You should install the first entry in the list:
[Generic Plus PS3 Printer Driver V2.00](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-advance-c5550i.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1816412&os=windows%2010%20%2864-bit%29&language=en).

The other downloads are for specialized rendering engines which are risky to use,
or are for older versions (the latest is V2.00 from  28 February 2019).

Comment: You have so much rep that a meagre upvote that I can't yet even cast is certainly meaningless now, but I should have said thank you at least. So, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can always mark an answer on your own question as accepted (click the ✔ sign), if the answer was helpful in solving the problem.